# JPA Hibernate SQL Query to NOT fetch data from one of the associated tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to make use of JPA query to fetch the data from DB using below query:

```
from Candidate c where c.id = :id
```

where, id = candidate_id(primary key of main table).

This query fetch the data from all of its associated tables as well, whereas my requirement is to fetch the data only from 2 of its associated tables. Because 3rd table contains heavy JSON data which degrades the response time of above query.

I tried using **JOIN**, **Fetch JOIN** of parent with its 2 associated tables but it didn't work. I was also looking into how we can skip just one column data(column of 3rd table with heavy JSON) while fetching the Candidate data but with no luck.

Is it possible to achieve it using JPA query or I need to try something else? I am good to save candidate and all its associated tables data in one go using `repo.save(candidate)` but don't want to fetch one of the related tables data.

This is how I have made the association in spring-boot:

CANDIDATE ENTITY:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,                              
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,                                   
        mappedBy = "candidate")                                    
@JsonManagedReference                                             
private Address address;                            
                                                                  
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,                             
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,                                   
        mappedBy = "candidate")                                    
@JsonManagedReference                                             
private Set<Skills> skills= new HashSet<>();                    
                                                                  
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,                             
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,                                   
        mappedBy = "candidate")                                    
@JsonManagedReference                                             
private Set<Prefrence> prefrences = new HashSet<>();
```

ADDRESS ENTITY:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Candidate candidate;
```

SKILLS ENTITY:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Candidate candidate;
//rest of the fields
```

PREFERENCE ENTITY:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Candidate candidate;
//rest of the fields
```

I don't want to fetch Preference entity data when using `candidateRepo.findById(id)` It should be always null in fetched Candidate
Attached the diagram
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1irF3.png)

Comment: If it shouldn't be fetched why do you map it?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I mapped it to save the data of a candidate in all the associated tables in one go. i.e. repo.save(candidate).

Comment: Your requirement does not match how JPA works.

Comment: ok..you mean if we are saving the data via mapping, then it will bring back the data as well everything...is it? No JPA query can help me out

Comment: That's the way it works. You have set the fetch type to lazy but then the candidate will contain a proxy that will trigger the load if you access the property

Comment: just an update, I am now exploring criteria and projections for the same. Also, if someone knows if we have field level annotation in spring boot to skip the particular column (like we have @JsonIgnore in jackson) which would tell hibernate not to fetch that column data.

Comment: There is no annotation for that. Because that way you'd get an incomplete entity and if you for whatever reason try to save the candidate my be deleted (depending on the cascading)

Comment: Thank you @SimonMartinelli...I appreciate your quick help...will look for a different approach then :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a DTO and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Candidate.class)
public interface CandidateDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    AddressDto getAddress();
    Set<SkillsDto> getSkills();

    @EntityView(Address.class)
    interface AddressDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
    @EntityView(Skills.class)
    interface SkillsDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`CandidateDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, CandidateDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<CandidateDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!